# $\cos x=\arccos x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Graphing gives the solution to be $0.739,$ but I want to know how to find that value mathematically. I imagine I'd have to use trigonometric identities, but how to go about it?

Comment: The solution is the same as the solution for $x=\cos(x)$. Do you see why ?

Comment: ... therefore, it suffices to use iteration $x_{n+1}=\cos(x_n)$

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303440/find-the-limit-of-coscos-cos1)

Comment: If you love playing pocket calculator, you could try repeatingly using $\cos (.)$ started with any number.

Answer (score 0):

> $$\cos x=\arccos x$$

$\arccos$ has domain $[-1,1]$ and is a decreasing function, $\arccos(\cos1)=1,$ and $\cos x\not>1.$

Thus, [the required solution](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f1s5snuiij) lies within $[\cos 1,1].$ On this domain,

$$\cos x=\arccos x\\\iff
\cos(\cos x)=\cos(\arccos x)\\\iff
x=\cos(\cos x);$$ there is no analytic solution.

Now, $\sin(\cos x)<1,$ so $$\Big|\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\cos(\cos x)\Big|=\lvert(\sin x)\sin(\cos x)\rvert\\<1.$$ Therefore, within $[\cos 1,1],$ the required solution is an [attracting fixed point](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3373798/21813) of $\cos(\cos x),$ and consequently of $\cos x.$

Thus, by solving $x_{n+1}=\cos x_n$ iteratively (using $x_0=1,$ say), the required solution is $0.739,$ the [Dottie number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottie_number).