# Find the limit of: cos(cos(...cos1)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, trigonometry

Find the limit of cosine composing with itself n times:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left ( cos(cos(\cos(...\cos1 \right )$

I have worked on it a bit:
The sequence is: 0,1,cos(1),cos(cos1),...
I identified the function mapping [0,1] to [0,1] and the function is decreasing in this interval.
Then I saw that if even terms sequence is increasing the odd ones is decreasing.

$${a_{2n}}\le{a_{2n+1}}.$$
Then compose of two decreasing functions is increased on [0,1].
I stuck here :(
Would it be enough to show that $${a_{2n+1}-a_{2n}}\le{k}(a_{2n-1}-a_{2n-2})$$ for some k: 0<k<1

I have saw an answer on this site but I could not understand. It says that from Mean Value Theorem  there exist a number x of the segment [a2n-1,a2n-2] which is on [0,1] so that:
(a2n-1 - a2n-2)*sin(cosx)*sinx

0 < sin(cosx)*sinx < sin(cos1)*sin1= k < 1

and this:

$${a_{2n+1}-a_{2n}}\le{k}(a_{2n-1}-a_{2n-2})$$

This wasn't clear for me, from mean value theorem. Did he used that for function or for the sequence?
should we take an=f(n)
and then (an-1 - a2n-2)*sin(cosx)*sinx=
then for [x1,x2]; f
(f(x1)-f(x2))=f'(an)(x2-x1) ?
Could we use that in this way? Please can someone clarify the part from mean value theorem becuase I couldn't understand it.

Comment: See the [Dottie Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html).

Comment: The limit solves $x=\cos(x)$. The unique real number satisfying this equality is transcendental.

Comment: This is a good question, and you've shown good effort in working on it, but it is difficult to read in parts due to inconsistent use of MathJAX.  Would you mind taking a few minutes to apply `\cos` and `$` and subscript `_` markings to make your work easier to read?

Comment: @abiessu okay I will try to fix that.